# The meaning of "pushes a paper of buttons at us"

Tags: meaning

> Well, then, coming home by Drinker's Alley to get a new shirt which a
>   French Vicomte's lady was washing **to take the stiff out of (I'm
>   always choice in my body-linen) a lame Frenchman pushes a paper of
>   buttons at us.**  He hadn't long landed in the United States, and
>   please would we buy. He sure-ly was a pitiful scrattel--his coat half
>   torn off, his face cut, but his hands steady; so I knew it wasn't
>   drink.  He said his name was Peringuey, and he'd been knocked about in
>   the crowd round the Stadt--Independence Hall.

This is from "Rewards and Fairies" "A Priest in Spite of Himself" by Kipling.
http://pinkmonkey.com/dl/library1/digi300.pdf

What is the meaning of:

> *"to take the stiff out of (I'm always choice in my body-linen) a lame Frenchman pushes a paper of buttons at us."*

I  can not understand the meaning below.

> - to take the stiff out of
> - be  always choice in one's body-linen
> - push a paper of buttons at

I am glad if someone kindly teach me.

Answer (score 3):

*Get the stiff out of* — new linen is stiff; it takes repeated washings to make it soft.

*Be choice in my body-linen*—to *be choice* is 18th-century idiom for being 'picky', demanding something be just to one's taste. *Body-linen* is linen garments worn next to the body: for an 18th-century woman her shift, for an 18th-century man his shirt and possibly drawers.

*Pushed a paper of buttons*—buttons are still typically sold in multiples, stitched to a paper or card; the lame Frenchman is scraping out a meagre living by selling buttons in the street, much as refugees today hawk DVDs and t-shirts and caps on the sidewalks of European and (when they can get in) American cities.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the washing is to remove the starch that has been used to stiffen the cuffs and collar of the shirt. I think the reference to "new shirt" means a "fresh, clean shirt".

So in the text

> to take the stiff out of (I'm always choice in my body-linen) a lame
>   Frenchman pushes a paper of buttons at us.

we are left with

- "always choice" - always choosey in modern usage
- lame Frenchman - a man limping on a damaged leg
- paper of buttons - as the first respondent mentioned, a set of buttons was usually sewn onto a card or bit of paper to be sold as a collection